# React Router 4 can not load new content on same component with <Link>

Tags: react-router-v4

I can't seem to trigger any other react component life cycle method other than render() when I click on a link that leads to a page that loads exactly the same component, even though the url is different.  So here's my code

```
//index.js - the entry point
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Config from './Settings/Config';
import App from './Components/App';

const c = new Config();
render(
  <BrowserRouter basename={c.routerBaseName}>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Here's my App JS

```
//  Components/App.js

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Route} from 'react-router-dom';

import BlogEntry from './BlogEntry';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {

    console.log('app');
    return (
        <div>
          <Route exact path="/blog/:name" component={BlogEntry} />
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And here is my BlogEntry.js

```
// Components/BlogEntry.js
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class BlogEntry extends React.Component {

  async componentDidMount() {
    const [r1] = await Promise.all([
        fetch(`http://api.myservice.com/${this.props.match.params.name}`)
    ]);
    this.setState({content:await r1.json()});
    console.log('fetch');
  }
  render() {
    console.log('render');
    if(!this.state) return <div></div>;
    if(!this.state.content) return <div></div>;

    const content = this.state.content;

    return (
      <div id="blog-entry" className="container">
          <h1>{content.title}</h1>
          <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:content.content}}></div>
          <div className="related-other">
          <h2>Related Content</h2>
          <ul>
            <li><Link to="/blog/new-york-wins-the-contest">New York Wins the Contest!</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/blog/toronto-with-some-tasty-burgers">Toronto with Some Tasty Burgers</Link></li>
          </ul>
          </div>
      </div>

    );
  }
}
```

So what happens is that when I click on the link for `Toronto with Some Tasty Burgers` or `New York Wins the Contest!` I see the url in my web browser address bar update accordingly.  But my componentDidMount does not fire.  And hence no new content is fetched or loaded.

React also won't let me put an `onPress` event handler to the `<Link>` object.  And even if I did, managing the history state when browser clicks back button would be a nightmare if I were to create my own onpress event handler to load pages.

So my question is, how do I make it so that clicking on one of the links actually causes the component to fetch new data and redraw and also be part of the browser back button history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this to my BlogEntry.js and everything works now:

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      this.props = nextProps;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your proposed solution, via componentWillReceiveProps (deprecated) is good enough. It's a hack.
Why don't you keep the route id in the state (as in /blog/**:id**).

Then something like this:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
     const { match: { params: { id: postId } = {} } } = this.props;
     if(this.state.postId !== postId) {
       // fetch content
    }
}
```